# How do you indicate there's a tooltip present in a radio button or checkbutton?

Tags: c#, tooltip

I have a radio button with a tooltip associated. But i want the user to immediatly recognize there's a tooltip there. I've heard of some programs that use a yellow question mark inside a circumference. 
Does the same exist on c#?

Comment: You can add one. I doubt you get it "for free"

Comment: Also there is: WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET all of them C#. It is not clear which technology you intend to use.

Comment: @Noctis guess its time to check charmap :(

Comment: a upperscript question mark would do the trick, but cant find it on character map

Comment: Seems I didn't understand you then, and been a bit of an Ѡ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public void adornQM(Control ctl)
{
    Label QM = new Label();
    QM.Text = "?";
    QM.Font = new Font("Arial", 6f, FontStyle.Regular);
    QM.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    QM.Location = new Point(ctl.Width - 8, 0);
    ctl.Controls.Add(QM);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
adornQM(checkBox1);
adornQM(radioButton1);
```

It adds a Label to the Control's Controls collection. It works best if the Control's text has a trailing blank or two.

With a little extra effort you can twist it more or less any way by owner-drawing..:

```
public void adornQM(Control ctl)
{
    Label QM = new Label();
    QM.Font = new Font("Arial", 7f, FontStyle.Regular);
    QM.Location = new Point(ctl.Width - 13, 0);
    QM.Paint += QM_Paint;
    ctl.Controls.Add(QM);
}

void QM_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Label  QM = sender as Label;
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0, 12, 12);
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.DarkSlateBlue, 0, 0, 12, 12);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("?", QM.Font, Brushes.Black, 2, 1);
}
```

Both versions will add an extra Control for each Control you adorn. Instead you could owner draw all the Controls themselves, but that looks rather like more work..

Comment: Awesome answer, really wasn't expecting something like that.

Comment: One doubt, where should i place the adornQM method? in the usual class it will give ambiguous error, so i tried it on form1.designer.cs but the error stayed the same.

Comment: I have __placed__ it at the form class level. What 'ambiguous error,' do you get? I __called__ the function in the constructor after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: On the first control before ctl argument:  'Control' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' and 'System.Windows.Controls.Control'

Comment: Oh. Well let's see: You still have not told us which platform you are developing for: Winforms, WPF, ASP..?? The `System.Windows.Controls.Control` namespace belongs to __WPF__. If you are __not__ doing WPF you should either not reference it, or, if you __really__ need it you will have to qualify the ambiguous members like `Control` fully as: `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

Comment: It's visual c# 2010 express.. I know this is not the expected answer, but honestly it's all i know, I'd really like to understand that error, it's not the first time it shows up and i've no idea why since i'm just starting to program. I've used System.Windows.Forms.Control to solve it before.

Comment: LOL, yes , that is not the answer we need. Do you have a `Form1` in your project? Look at the using clauses: Is there `using System.Windows.Forms;` among them?  That would be a Winforms application. Or do you have a `MainWindow`? and is there `using System.Windows.Input;` among the using clauses at the top of the window code? That would be a WPF application. you decide which application platform when you create a new project..

Comment: Yes I have a Form1, it's using using System.Windows.Forms; and
using System.Windows.Controls; So Is this where the conflict comes from? What is the difference between forms and controls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60406/discussion-between-taw-and-ng80092a).